# Why type-deduction for arrays prioritizes pointer to first over reference to array?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, auto, type-deduction

```
int v[1];
auto  p1 = v;
auto &p2 = v;
auto *p3 = v;
```

`p1` is of type `int *` (same for `p3`). Particularly at this trivial sample I find `p2` ( `int (&)[1]` ) more useful since it inherents array semantics, e.g. I can apply `sizeof` on `p2` to give the same as `sizeof` on `v`.

Is there a standard quotation regarding that?

Why defaulting to references is a bad idea? (for this arrays case I mean, almost no c++ programmer cares about them these days anyway...)

Comment: `Is there a standard quotation regarding that?` 7.1.6.4/7 specifies that the rules for type deduction with `auto` are the same (modulo `initializer_list`) as the rules for template argument deduction. Then, 14.8.2.1/2 (for template argument deduction) specifies that decay from array type to pointer type only occurs for non-reference parameters.

Comment: It might also be of interest to note that the same applies to function types. If you change the definition of `v` to `void v()`, then `p1` is `void(*)()` but `p2` is `void(&)()`

Comment: C doesn't have references, so arrays decay to pointers when passed as function arguments. C++ inherited the behavior from C for compatibility.

Comment: @Praetorian yeah, in the end, I think I'm discussing the gender of the angels...

Comment: You forget `auto &&p4 = v;` which is `int (&)[1]` as `p2`.

Answer (score 4):

`auto` deduces a non-reference type.

`auto&` deduces a reference.

`auto const&` deduces a `const` reference.

`auto&&` deduces either a reference, a `const` reference, or an rvalue reference.

This works just like how type deduction when calling a `template` function works.

```
template<typename T>
void foo( T t );
```

`T` will *never* be deduced by be a reference type -- it will always be a value type when deduced.

`auto` follows almost identical rules:

```
template<typename T>
void foo( T&& t );
```

is the reasonably well known "universal reference", analogous to a variable of type `auto&&`.

Comment: authoritative answers deserve quotations ;-) anyway, Andy Prowl commented it well, sad it's not an answer. The standard says so, still, I'd like to know historical reasons and/or strong argumentation on how it couldn't be without bringing too much trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's for consistency with non-template functions. Arrays undergo the array-to-pointer conversion anytime they're accessed, except when being bound to a reference. So with the existing rules, the following are consistent:

```
int v[1];

void foo(int *);

int main()
{
  foo(v);
}
```

and

```
int v[1];

template <class T>
void foo(T);

int main()
{
  foo(v);
}
```

Comment: type deduction in the templated code is somewhat similar to `auto`. I mean I could do the same question using templates in plain c++98 =). but anyway, I can foresee template arguments resolving to arrays references like it could be for auto, still the questioning remains, where this is worst? I know the rule about array decaying to pointers, but I'm not seeing it precluding binding to reference over a pointer type. I see, there's a consistency with the decay to pointer rule though...

Comment: @pepper_chico Type deduction for templated code is almost exactly the same as `auto` (the other way round, actually); that's why I used a template in the answer. Also note that this would be the only case when a parameter not including a lexical `&` or `&&` can deduce to a reference - quite an ugly exception, I'd say.