# How to apply range based loop to array of arrays in C++11?

Tags: arrays, pointers, c++11, foreach

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    int arr2[4] = {5,6,7,8};
    int **arrPtr;

    arrPtr[0] = arr;
    arrPtr[1] = arr2;

    for (int *a : arrPtr ){
        for (int i : a){
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I know this implementation is not the way to go but to show the intension at the end. Basically I am trying to print the content of arrays listed by another double pointer.
Is there any way to make this code work?

Comment: That's not an array of arrays, that's just erroneous code. `*arrPtr` doesn't point anywhere, so assigning to it is illegal.

Comment: Are you expecting 8 lines of output (4 + 4) or 16 (4 * 4)? Also, did you know that ranged for works on arrays? `for (int a : arr){cout << a << endl;}` will give you `1 2 3 4` with no pointers in sight

Comment: I just try to learn c++11 not much and revise some pointer... I just try to print out all of the items below one another

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int m[][4] = {
                    { 0, 1, 2, 3 },
                    { 4, 5, 6, 7 },
                    { 8, 9, 0, 1 },
                    { 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                 };

    for(auto &line : m) {
        for(auto &value : line) {
            std::cout << value << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d603241402fcc886

#### bonus

notice that this also work:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for(auto &line : (int [][4])
            {
                { 0, 1, 2, 3 },
                { 4, 5, 6, 7 },
                { 8, 9, 0, 1 },
                { 2, 3, 4, 5 },
            }) {
        for(auto &value : line) {
            std::cout << value << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you explain what is that auto and referencing ?

Comment: @Erogol it's c++11 type deduction feature, so that you don't need to state types explicitely when the compiler should already have this figured out. You are asking the compiler: you know what type it's, so I want `line` and `value` of that type. Using a reference variable (auto &) **is necessary**, because without it, `line` would be just a pointer without array size information, which is required for range-for.
check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982514/why-type-deduction-for-arrays-prioritizes-pointer-to-first-over-reference-to-arr

Answer (score 0):

The new range-for loop does not work on raw pointer types as they don't contain size information. If you know their lengths in compile time, you can cast them as pointers to arrays and use in range-for. Such code may be good to play with but use `std::array`, `std::vector` for real uses.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    int arr2[4] = {5,6,7,8};
    unique_ptr<int*[]> arrPtrHolder(new int*[2]);
    int **arrPtr = arrPtrHolder.get();

    arrPtr[0] = arr;
    arrPtr[1] = arr2;

    for (int *a : *(int*(*)[2])(arrPtr)){
        for (int i : *(int (*)[4])(a)){
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a207f5c4853b1e1f